# Appropriate Way to Retrieve Records From Meteor via FlowRouter Param

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The code I've got to do a select right now is this:

```
stories.findOne({ _id:new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID(FlowRouter.getParam("_id"))})
```

this seems like overkill. Is this the properly optimized way to do a find from MongoDB from Meteor using FlowRouter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor's collection methods allow you to use an id string directly as the selector:

```
stories.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam("_id"))
```

BTW, I believe it is still best practice to use capitalized variable names for collections (i.e., `Stories`).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Curious, why is capitalization important?

Comment: It's a convention that you will see people using. The collection in mongo should be called "stories", and the variable you use to reference it should be called "Stories". The difference is very subtle.

Comment: Jesse, glad it works! Could you accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if I got something wrong in the first place, but it seemed to be working and now it's not. I'm back to:

```Stories.findOne({ _id:new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID(FlowRouter.getParam("_id"))})```

This works. 

This doesn't: ```stories.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam("_id"))```